# Bash: Read from host list, Create/Touch file while adding content

Tags: linux, bash

Looking to read from a list of hosts that has a hostname,ip. Would like to create a file for the hostname and add the ip into it. This is for ansible host_var file.

```
HOSTS="\
10.10.10.1,host1 \
10.10.10.2,host2 \
10.10.10.3,host3 \
"

cmd() {
  touch /tmp/test/$HOST
}

for j in $HOSTS; do
  IP='echo $j | cut -d: -f1'
  export HOST='echo $j | cut -d: -f2'
  cmd echo "ansible_host: $IP" > $HOST
done
```

A more simple version..

```
HOSTS="10.10.10.1,host1
10.10.10.2,host2
10.10.10.3,host3"

while IFS="," read -ra line; do
  echo "ansible_host: '${line[0]}'" > "${line[1]}"
done <<< "$HOSTS"
```

While I have omitted 400 ish hosts. The error I getting on both these .sh scripts is on the echo line.

./touchfile.sh: line 425:  echo: command not found
./touchfile.sh: line 425:  echo: command not found

Any help on what im doing wrong?

Comment: The code you show would not produce that error, if only because you aren't showing 425 lines of code. You need to ensure that the code shown *here* produces an error.

Comment: you want `HOST=$(echo $j | cut -d: -f2)` (or you  can replace $( ) with back-tics and have stone-age compatible cmd-substitution. But I don't see how `echo "ansible_host: $IP" > $HOST`, will be correctly processed by your `cmd()` as defined above. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! yeah the used of a function was over kill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store the values in a variable; use a here document. Also, there's no need for an array; just give `read` separate names for each field.

```
while IFS=, read -r addr name; do
    printf "ansible_host: '%s'\n" "$addr" >> "$name"
done <<EOF
10.10.10.1,host1
10.10.10.2,host2
10.10.10.3,host3
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks this worked the way i wanted with a small tweak.  I removed the single quote on %s as I was getting ansible_host: '10.10.10.10'. so now I have ansible_host: 10.10.10.10. So simple appreciate the quick help!